# Animating Button .Repeat make @IBAction Not working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

When I animate the Button with Repeat and Autoreverse options the `@IBAction` is not working.

**Animation Code:**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 50, height: 50)
}, completion: nil)
```

**Action Code:**

```
@IBAction func btnAction(sender: UIButton) {
   label.text = "Button pressed"
}
```

Comment: You will need to enable user interactions during animation. Add option . AllowUserInteraction  along with Repeat and Autoreverse.

Comment: I have a similar issue, and added .AllowUserInteraction as suggested but the button is still not selected. Any help much appreciated!                          func nextButtonWink() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0, options: [.AllowUserInteraction, .Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut, .Autoreverse],
            animations: {
                self.nextButton.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `.allowUserInteraction` to the options parameter as noted by @Shripada

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 50, height: 50)
}, completion: nil)
```